# Game Maker: Studio Android Not Compiling

Tags: android, compiler-warnings, game-maker

So I'm using GameMaker Studio Pro: 1.4.1657. I've installed all necessary SDKs, NDKs and other permissions. However, I cannot create and executable(.apk) for android.

Here is what the console says:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\tools\ant\build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\tools\ant\build.xml:694: null returned: 1

Total time: 15 seconds
```

I've tried this solution: [link](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=590513) Which didn't work.

Thanks! I would've posted this in the yoyogames forums, but I can't post! Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry for the long wait! Thanks for responding so quickly! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlD-4GKK6cdclQtSmlUY1QweFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have `-` in package name or in project name?

Comment: In the gamemaker project? Yes I do, it's Destructopus_rev_9.gmx . Should I remove the underscores?

Comment: Not underscore `_` but minus `-`

Comment: No, I don't. Somehow, I was able to compile a new project with only one room. But with my current project, I can't compile it!